# Why can't the m be dropped in O(n^2 +m)?

Tags: big-o, notation

Since Big O is a measure of how code scales, shouldn't the n^2 scale much faster than m? I don't see how the specific values are relevant

Comment: I'm not an expert on Big O notation, but I've never seen it used with the addition or subtraction of a value. My understanding is that notations such as Big O are named "asymptotic notations" ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) specifically because they describe time-complexity at its extremes, at which point addition and subtraction are negligible. Do you have a source or example for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the complexity and big O has, or rather depends on, two variables. For example, a lot of graph algorithms use **E** and **V** for the number of edges and vertices. If **m** was constant or derived from **n** then the usual analysis could allow reducing it. However, we can imagine (probably quite artificial) cases were, say **m=n^3** and hence is of higher order than the **m^2** term.

One contrived example I came with is having an array **N** of **n** elements and a huge list **M** of **m** elements to check if the elements are within the first array. We naively choose to use bubble sort  ( **O n^2** ) and use binary search on the sorted array **N**  for each element within **M**.

We would have **O(n^2+ m + log(n) )**.
After reducing **log n** as a lower order of magnitude we end up having **O(n^2+m)**.

Instead of bike sort of an array we could have cross self join that has to be checked m times.